# How can I search a string to know if it contains a date and extract it?

Tags: android

I have a code which reads messages and if the message has a date in it then It should specifically be shown in display. I am stuck at the part where I have to search the entire `string` for the date and extract it?

Comment: Is the date have a common format?

Comment: Post your code what you have tried

Comment: we can do dat if d date has perticular format

Comment: You can achieve it if there is specific date format.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help.I am trying to search for the date in dd/mm/yy format?

Answer (score 0):

Try using regular expressions below is pseudo code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, ParseException {
    String string = "Temp_2014_09_19_01_00_00.csv";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d\\d\\d\\d_\\d\\d_\\d\\d");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
    Date tempDate = null;
    if(m.find())
    {
        tempDate = format.parse(m.group());
    }
    System.out.println("" + tempDate);
}
```

The regex looks for 4digits_2digits_2digits then it takes that match if it finds one and tries to convert it into a date. If it doesn't find a match then tempDate will be null. If you want to bring in the timestamp also you can do that too.